# is it possible to use both androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme & androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme in Android application

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am investigating Android Jetpack Compose in my current Android application.

I wish to have the main screen contain a backdrop and show selected options on the front layer.

I also require my application to support Dark Mode.

It seems to me that I must employ both `androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme` & `androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme` to theme my application.

This is because `androidx.compose.material.BackdropScaffold` is a material component, which means it ignores my `androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme` values.

however i would like my application to take advantage of Material components as much as possible.

Is it possible to configure multiple `MaterialTheme`(s) in this case?
Do I have to wait for a `Material3` version of `BackdropScaffold`?

Answer (score 1):

It will be Challenging!  I am guessing you are using Android & **NOT** Compose

There is Not a direct correlation between the `androidx.compose.material3.Typography`
also Material 3 ColorScheme is much extended, to make te colors work you will need to defind the colors to match, well those that can, and make use you import the correct library when using the MaterialTheme Libraries

Otherwise I see no reason why not to try migrate as material 3 comes to maturity!

My Compose/Material3 App have similar roblems because they disabled support for `rememberScaffoldState()` in the Scaffold, I had to implement that myself as seperate `DrawerState` and `SnackbarHostState`